# How to switch from 'SetInterval' to 'request animation frame'

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

I have created a simple canvas animation and I heard that it is better to use 'request animation frame' than 'setinterval', but I'm not sure how to do it?

This is how it looks like at the moment:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/rC7zJ/
```

```
var width = 48;
var height = 87;
var speed = 100; //ms
var frames = 1; // Total frames - 1, as frame start from 0 not 
var currentFrame = 0;

canvas = document.getElementById("CanvasAnimate");
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
imageTadPole = new Image()
imageTadPole.src = 'https://dl.dropbox.com/u/19418366/tadpole.png';

function draw(){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    ctx.drawImage(imageTadPole, width * currentFrame, 0, width, height, 0, 0, width, height);

    if (currentFrame == frames) {
        currentFrame = 0;
    } else {
        currentFrame++;
    }
}

setInterval(draw, speed);
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/

Comment: I believe this is a good question and shouldn`t have been closed!!!Many people can have the same promblem and they can learn from this example!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Always start with Paul Irish’s great cross-browser shim for requestAnimationFrame

```
    window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback) {
      return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
      function(callback) {
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
      };
    })();
```

Then just code an animation function that:

1. Updates the variables that drive your animation( location, velocity, color changes, etc)
2. Draws the current frame using canvas’ context
3. Keeps the animation alive for the next frame by re-calling requestAnimFrame

Here’s example skeleton code:

```
    function animate() {

      // update animation variables
      X+=20;
      Velocity +=10;

      // clear the canvas and draw the current frame
      // based on the variables you just updated
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      ctx.rect(x,y,75,50);

      // request new frame to keep the animation going
      requestAnimFrame( animate );
    }
```

Here is how to throttle down your animation (like FPS--but not):

```
// set a countdown "throttle" that will slow animate() down by 4X
var notEveryTime=3;

function animate() {

  // if notEveryTime hasn't counted down to 0
  // then just don't animate yet
  if(--notEveryTime>0){ return; };

  // update animation variables
  X+=20;
  Velocity +=10;

  // clear the canvas and draw the current frame
  // based on the variables you just updated
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.rect(x,y,75,50);

  // request new frame to keep the animation going
  requestAnimFrame( animate );

  // reset notEveryTime
  notEveryTime=3;

}
```

And **do** read Anreas' good suggestion of: http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/

Comment: Thanks! but how am i suppose to control the fps :/? http://jsfiddle.net/rC7zJ, it is like lighting speed now :/

Comment: I added to my answer to include a standard "throttle" which you can set to manage your animation speed.  Note that requestAnimation frame does not use a specific FPS--it will just animate as fast/efficient as it can.  If you need a more specific timing, be sure to read this great article on combining requestAnimationFrame with setTimeout: http://creativejs.com/resources/requestanimationframe/

Answer (score 1):

What marke said, but if you want to control the FPS, wrap your requestAnimationFrame call in a setTimeOur function, like so:

```
var fps = 15;
function draw() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        requestAnimationFrame(draw);
        // Drawing code goes here
    }, 1000 / fps);
}
```

It is a good idea to use requestAnimationFrame, even if you're fixing your frame rate, as it

1. will provide CPU throttling when the page is inactive a
2. gives you the behind-the-scene optimisations requestAnimationFrame provides.

A good page on Request Animation Frame can be found [here](http://creativejs.com/resources/requestanimationframe/).

Comment: Chuckle...great minds think alike. :)